# python - re.S/re.DOTALL flag not supported by re.sub

Tags: python, regex

Is it me or is it a bug in python ?

```
>>> re.sub(r'.*', '', 'a\nb', re.M | re.S)
'\n'
>>> re.sub(r'(.|\n)*', '', 'a\nb', re.M | re.S)
''
```

And, strangely, it works with `re.search`:

```
>>> re.search(r'.*', 'a\nb', re.M | re.S)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='a\nb'>
```

EDIT: I've added the `re.M` flag to make it clearer

Comment: duplicate. Don't forget to use the `flags=` keyword.

Comment: `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)` and `re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)`

Comment: You don't need flags argument even with inline modifiers `(?s).*`

Comment: "Is it me or is it a bug in python ?": 99,9% of the time it's you :) in that case it's an easy trap to fall in.

Comment: at least it adds an answer on google for the next time I forget about the `count` arg :) Thanks for you answer !